# While goback to previous page getting slow to loading in windows phone 8.1 winRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have firstPage and secondPage in my project, to navigate from first page. I use the following code

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(secondPage));
```

and to go back from the secondPage, i used the NavigationHelper class, to go back to the previous page, the first page contains listview with 100 dataitems.

While navigating to first page is getting very slow, and is there any way for fast navigation, I also tried Dispatcher but not improving the speed.

```
DataItems = new IncrementalLoadingCollection<EmpTables>
        (async (currentPage,pageSize) => 
 {
    return await Task.Run<IEnumerable<EmpTables>>(() => 
    { 
         return Source.Skip(currentPage * pageSize).Take(pageSize); 
    }); 
 }, 5);
```

this ViewModel.DataItems property binding into the listview itemssource.

Comment: You should post the code that's filling the listview.

Comment: added the code sample

Answer (score 0):

What if you add this in the firstPage.xaml file?

```
NavigationCacheMode="Enabled"
```